# how to make tcl script continue on error?

Tags: error-handling, tcl

I'm new tcler.
I have a file file1.tcl:

```
set a "MY_TEST"
set b [format "%.1f" [expr $a-3]]
puts $b
puts $a
```

I cannot modify file1,
and I use another file, file2.tcl to source file1:

File2.tcl:

```
catch { source file1.tcl } result
```

it will show error expression "$a -3" when puts $b, as expected

I want tcl show this error, but also continue to put $a, how to do that?
(can have way to auto set b to 0 when error?)

Answer (score 1):

Tcl is not designed to work that way; once the interpreter encounters an error (or other exceptional condition) it unwind outwards until it finds something that handles the error. You can set execution traces to observe this, but you don't get to change what the result tuple is. The key problem is you don't really know what the state *should be* in that case; you only really know what it *is,* an error.

You could replace `expr` with your own version (use a child interpreter — see `interp create` — if you plan to do that; see below) that handles errors and substitutes something else, but that is really easy to make confusing code from. I don't recommend it because you don't really know what the script is using the `expr` to do ahead of time.

```
interp create helper
helper eval {
    rename expr realExpr
    proc expr args {
        try {
            return [uplevel 1 [list realExpr {*}$args]]
        } on error {msg} {
            puts "WARNING: $msg"
            return 0
        }
    }
}

set result [helper eval {source file1.tcl}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script will actually already fail on the `set b [format "%.1f" [expr $a-3]]` line.

For simple cases like your example, you can read the input file command by command, execute each command on its own and catch and report errors:

```
proc runcmd {str} {
    if {[info complete $str]} {
        if {[catch {uplevel #0 $str} err]} {
            # Strip the trailing newline or semicolon
            set cmd [string range $str 0 end-1]
            puts stderr "$err\n   while executing\n$cmd\n"
        }
        return 1
    } else {
        return 0
    }
}

set fd [open file1.tcl]
while {[gets $fd line] >= 0} {
    foreach next [lassign [split $line {;}] str] {
        append cmd $str {;}
        set str $next
        if {[runcmd $cmd]} {set cmd ""}
    }
    append cmd $str \n
    if {[runcmd $cmd]} {set cmd ""}
}
close $fd
```

This will correctly handle the input file, even if it is written as:

```
set a \
  "MY_TEST"
set b [format "%.1f;" [expr $a-3]]
puts $b; puts $a
```

However, it will still run loops and conditional commands in one go.

If you also like this to execute individual commands inside loops and conditional blocks, you'll definitely want to run the commands in a child interpreter as Donal suggested. You then define your own `if`, `while`, and `foreach` commands for this interpreter that recursively process their bodies in a similar way.